# Using a while loop for conditional read of text file

Tags: python

Keeping it simple, [omitting scale and parallelism], I'm trying to read a text file. On that text file, there are entries which run over more than one line (other software has character entry limits). An example is below

```
#Iterating through the file
with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
     #Examining each line
     for line in file:
         #If the first three characters meet a condition
         if line[:3] == "aa ":
             #If the last character is not a condition
             if line.rstrip()[-1:] != "'":
                   #Then this entry effectively runs onto *at least* the next line
                   #Store the current line in a buffer for reuse
                   temp = line

                   #Here is my issue, I don't want to use a 'for line in file' again, as that would require me to write multiple "for" & "if" loops to consider the possibility of entries running over several lines
                   [Pseudocode]
                   while line.rstrip()[-1:] in file != "'":
                           #Concatenate the entries to date
                           temp = temp + line

                   #entry has completed
                   list.append(temp)

              else
                   #Is a single line entry
                   list.append(line)
```

But, its obviously not liking the while loop. I've had a look around and not come across anything. Anyone any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: please post a snippet of the text file?

Comment: This process would be a little simpler if you can read the whole file into RAM as a list of lines. Or is it too big to do that? But anyway, inside your main loop you can get the next line by doing `line = next(file)`.

Comment: Yeah, the next() command is useful, but don't believe you can iterate with it over i "next" lines if you know what I mean. 

Some of the files would be too big, my basic concept is to break them up and fire off multiprocessing, but want to make sure I don't lose multi-line entries when doing so.

edit: Ah, maybe it will - three of you now have suggested it so I guess it could do the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. I constructed my own sample input:

```
# Content of input.txt:
# This is a regular entry.
# aa 'This is an entry that
# continues on the next line
# and the one after that.'
# This is another regular entry.

entries = []
partial_entry = None  # We use this when we find an entry spanning multiple lines

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # If this is a continuation of a previous entry
        if partial_entry is not None:
            partial_entry += line

            # If the entry is now complete
            if partial_entry.rstrip()[-1] == "'":
                entries.append(partial_entry)
                partial_entry = None
        else:
            # If this is an entry that will continue
            if line.startswith("aa ") and line.rstrip()[-1] != "'":
                partial_entry = line
            else:
                entries.append(line)

# If partial_entry is non-None here, we have some entry that never terminated
assert partial_entry is None

print(entries)

# Output:
# ['This is a regular entry.\n', "aa 'This is an entry that\ncontinues on the next line\nand the one after that.'\n", 'This is another regular entry.\n']
```

**EDIT**

Based on PM2Ring's suggestion above, here's a solution using `next(file)`. (Same input and output as before.)

```
entries = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("aa "):
            while not line.rstrip().endswith("'"):
                line += next(file)
        entries.append(line)

print(entries)
```

Comment: Per the comments on the other solution, I think perhaps lines that don't start with "aa " are to be ignored. If so, the second solution should have the `entries.append` call indented, and the first solution requires even more changes.

Comment: Just to let you all know, going with += next() also includes the \n string.

This was removed after exiting the while loop using line = line.replace("\n","")

Comment: If you don't want the newlines, just `rstrip()` each line as you go.

Comment: `line = line.rstrip()` at the top of the loop and `line += next(file).rstrip()`. Then you can drop the `rstrip` in the `while` condition too.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#next) on a iterator to get only the next element, without disturbing the `for` loop:

```
#Iterating through the file
with open(fileName, 'r') as file:
     #Examining each line
     for line in file:
         #If the first three characters meet a condition
         if line[:3] == "aa ":
             while not line.rstrip().endswith("'"):
                 line += next(file)

             #entry has completed
             list.append(line)
```

Comment: Ah, looks like we came to this solution at the same time. :-) Minor issue: that `list.append(line)` shouldn't be indented inside the `if`.

Comment: indeed :) but based on code from OP, I'd say the indent is good

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess you're right. Perhaps lines that don't start with "aa " are to be ignored?

Comment: Just to let you all know, going with += next() also includes the \n string. This was removed after exiting the while loop using line = line.replace("\n","")

(in case someone else finds this in a search on down the line)

Answer (score 1):

When you read a line that is continued onto the next line, just stash the partial result in a variable and let the loop go to the next line and concatenate the lines.  For example:

```
#Iterating through the file
result = []
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
     buffer = ''
     #Examining each line
     for line in file:
         #If the first three characters meet a condition
         if line[:3] == "aa ":
             buffer += line
             #If the last character indicates that the line is NOT to be continued, 
             if line.rstrip()[-1:] == "'":
                 result.append(buffer)
                 buffer = ''
     if buffer:
         # Might want to warn the the last line expected continuation but no subsequent line was found
         result.append(buffer)
print result
```

Note that it might be better if the file is very large to use the `yield` statement to produce the lines of the result rather than accumulating them in a list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I ended up going with +=next() as it required far less rework.